# How to pass Azure Application Setting/Connection String to Angular App

Tags: angular, azure

I'm attempting to deploy my Services using Pulumi to make the easily reusable. For this I have a .NET Core API, SQL Server instance and an Angular Frontend. I want to make it so this can be deployed without needing to change any configuration. Right now I use an environment variable hardcoded in my Angular app to connect to the api:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  //api url
  API_URL: "http://api.example.com"
};
```

I want to move this to an `Application Setting` or `Connection String` so that this is dynamic and does not require a rebuild of the application for each instance to change the API URL. This is a relatively simple process with the API connecting to the Database, but I am unable to figure it out with Angular as it does not have direct access to `process.env` - like Node.js would.

One way I have been suggested to do this would be to upload a config file at runtime when I deploy with Pulumi but I am unable to figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have two suggestions:

1. Set the api end point with relative path like:  `API_URL: "/api"`, then you can use nginx or other proxy to delegate every request start with "/api" to your backend end point.
2. If you don't have a proxy server, you can add a configuration file like "endpoint.json" which contains the "API_URL" in your frontend project or other storage. Then you can add a service to load it before Angular app start. See how to do this [here](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-use-the-app-initializer-token-to-hook-into).